# Pound Sterling not working in Opencart

Tags: opencart, authorize.net, pound

I'm having issues with the Pound Sterling £ currency in Opencart (I use OC 1.5.1 and my payment gateway is Authorize.net). When a customer attempts to submit their order on the checkout page of my site with the Pound Sterling currency selected they receive this message:

**The page at https://mysite.com says:
The supplied currency code is either invalid**

How do I resolve this to allow customers who use the Pound Sterling to check out? I'm having trouble finding information about if this would be an issue with Opencart or with my payment gateway which is Authorize.net.

As far as I knew, the currency selector in Opencart is purely for informative purposes for the customer, because when they submit their orders the currency is automatically converted to USD $ and sent to Authorize.net for processing. Correct me if I'm wrong about this though?

Is there some kind of code that I need to edit/place into my Opencart to resolve this?

Thanks for your time !! I really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Just to update, I use the AIM Authorize.net api, and I've just checked it again, and it's not just the Pound Sterling that doesn't work. The Euro doesn't work either. Basically the only currency that a customer is able to complete the checkout process with is the USD.

Comment: Each Authorize.Net gateway can only have a single currency based on the merchant account it connects to.  If you want to accept more than one currency, you'll need multiple gateways and your shopping cart will need to switch based on the currency used.

Comment: rhldr, thanks for your help. So I would need to setup up two additional (one for Euros and one for Pound Sterling) Authorize.net gateways then? I wonder if it would be easier to allow the customer to choose a currency on the frontend, but on the backend it would be processed and sent to Authorize.net in USD funds. In that sense the frontend currency selections would be purely to allow customers to see what the cost would translate to in their respective currencies. I spoke with an Authorize.net rep today and they said it was an Opencart issue not an Authorize.net issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Correct.  You need multiple gateways when you use Authorize.Net because the associated merchant account only supports a single currency.  Plus, OpenCart needs to support switching the currency and connecting to the proper gateawy based on the selected currency.  That's a question to ask OpenCart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that Authorize.net is restricted to which country you operate your company from (https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A414). So for a company in the US you can only process CAD or USD thru Authorize.net.

I'm going to use Paypal for international (EURO, Pound Sterling) and Authorize.net for USD orders.